# Can I create an intent filter which will match {act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/groups}?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to build a group picker and as part of that I want to catch the following intent:

{act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/groups}

Which is launched by the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Groups.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

And in my manifest I try to catch it with this:

```
<activity android:name=".GroupPickerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="com.android.contacts/groups" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: couldn't you test it to find out?

Comment: @JoxTraex Well it doesn't seem to work. I've updated my question a bit to clarify what I'm after.